# Why am I unable to set NTFS permissions on %ProgramFiles%?

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs, file-permissions, windows-server-2019

Using an Admin user account on Windows Server 2019, I am trying to change NTFS permissions for a user account on `%ProgramFiles%`, `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`, and `%WinDir%`, but I get an `access denied` error since the folders are owned by `TrustedInstaller`.

- I've tried both basic and advanced permissions dialog, and if I use advanced dialog to change permissions on `C:`, it fails on those three folders when propagating the changes to sub items
- I assume it may be possible to change ownership on the folders, but I also assume that doing so would not be a good idea

Why does this happen and is there a way to avoid it?

- What I'm trying to achieve is to sandbox a user account, denying execute permission for all apps, except for two that will be used with a single automated purpose - one of which is located in a subfolder of `%ProgramFiles%`, the other on a separate drive.

Comment: Use AppLocker instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the folder's *current* ACL doesn't grant admin accounts the permission to set ACLs. If you're not the owner, then you can't change ACLs unless explicitly granted that kind of access – that goes for admins too.

(The access entry that would grant Full Control is marked `(IO)` for "Inherit Only"; it only has effect on child objects but not on the original folder.)

One way to bypass that would be to activate SeRestorePrivilege (e.g. using the PSPrivilege cmdlets) – which is what Explorer uses to set arbitrary owners – but it won't work with `icacls` as it manually disables the privilege again before making the changes. It might still work with a different tool though (maybe with PowerShell's own `Set-Acl`).

Another method is to use a tool like `gsudo --ti` that lets you run arbitrary commands with TrustedInstaller rights (in much the same way as Windows components get those rights).

Comment: Accepted as answer because it answers the question I actually asked. The comment from @JW0914 above is, on the other hand, probably more helpful in finding the most viable solution to achieve the underlying goal. Happy that I got both! :-)